# React Native bridge IOS native module undefined

Tags: ios, react-native

I am going to integrate a analytics native module for React Native project, when i trying to create the bridge for communicate between RN and native with below simple function, it always return undefined in IOS. i have already follow the document from  [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.67/native-modules-ios) , but i have not idea what is wrong.

"react": "17.0.2"

"react-native": "0.67.3"

xcode : 13.4.1

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Function undefined]

Comment: did you rebuild the project? (using `run-ios` command or directly from xcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just undo all the steps then it works now, i guess can not create swift and objective c Native bridge at the same time? because when i create swift Native bridge, i figure out that the analytics library only support objective c, then i create objective c Native bridge, after that the debugger always warning me
the function undefined.